# Deseo hallar si una palabra se encuentra dentro de un texto

Tags: python

Tengo una función que cree para comprobar si una palabra se encuentra dentro de un texto, pero me falta algo que no descifro para completarla y que funcione. Deseo que me sugieran que puedo agregar para cumplir el proposito.

```
text = input()
word = input()

def search():
    
    for i in word:
        
        if text == word:
        print("World found")
        else:
        print("World not found")
    
print(search(text, word))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Hay algunos errores de concepto en tu código y por eso no funciona.

Hay algo que se conoce como alcance ([`Scope`](https://platzi.com/tutoriales/1764-python-cs/7580-scope-o-alcance-computer-science/#:%7E:text=El%20scope%20o%20alcance%20es,despu%C3%A9s%20de%20haber%20sido%20declaradas.)) que delimita si una variable es "visible" para cierta sección de código

Cuando se define una función, por defecto todas las variables que se utilicen adentro de la función serán locales para dicha función sin importar que el nombre dado a dichas variables sea igual a variables definidas globalmente.

En tu caso, definiste dos variables globales `text` y `word` y en tu función pretendes utilizarlas, pero por defecto se utilizan las variables locales y por lo tanto la función piensa que tanto `text` como `word` son variables locales, que aunque tienen el mismo nombre que las globales, hacen referencia a diferentes secciones de memoria y por lo tanto no son las mismas.

Si en realidad quisieras utilizar las variables globales adentro de tu función entonces deberías hacer algo así:

```
def search():
    global text
    global word
```

La palabra `global` indica a la función que se utilizará una variable que ha sido definida en el alcance (`Scope`) global.

Otro problema es tu función no recibe ningún argumento ya que la defines así `def search()` pero al utilizarla deseas pasar 2 argumentos `print(search(text, word))` y por lo tanto te va a mandar errores.

Por último, para buscar si una palabra existe dentro de una cadena de caracteres (`string`), basta con utilizar `in`, por ejemplo:

```
if word in text:
```

Ejemplo completo aplicando los comentarios anteriores:

```
# Definimos 2 variables globales
text = input()
word = input()

# Definimos la función que acepta dos argumentos
# t que será el texto y w que será la palabra
def search(t, w):
    # Revisamos que la palabra exista dentro del texto
    if w in t:
        # Utilizamos return para enviar el mensaje al terminar la ejecución
        return "Word found"
    else:
        return "Word not found"
        
print(search(text, word))
```

Ejemplo del funcionamiento:

```
 esto es una prueba
 prueba
Word found
```

Comment: Entiendo solo me faltaba usar in en el if y estar pendiente de los parametros de la funcion.

Comment: Y los argumentos de la función

Answer (score 0):

Aquí hay otra forma, mucho más sencilla, Saludos

```
    # Pedimos el texto al usuario
    texto = input("Ingresa un texto: ")
    
    # Pedimos la palabra a buscar al usuario
    palabra = input("Ingresa una palabra a buscar: ")
    
    # Buscamos la palabra en el texto
    if palabra in texto:
      print("Se ha encontrado la palabra en el texto.")
    else:
      print("No se ha encontrado la palabra en el texto.

")
```